# Grails can't get to cascade save many-to-one from form

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a many-to-one relationship which I want to expose through a single form, but I can't get the cascade-save to work, I don't see any error/exceptions in the log. Here's the domain classes:

```
class Person {
  String name
  List reminders = new ArrayList()
  static hasMany = [ reminders : PEvent ]
  static mapping = { reminders cascade:"all-delete-orphan" }
  def getRemindersList() {
    return LazyList.decorate(eventos, FactoryUtils.instantiateFactory(PEvent .class))
  }
}
class PEvent implements Comparable {
  static belongsTo = [person:Person ]
  static transients = [ '_deleted' ]
  String eventType
  Date eventDate
  String comments
  boolean _deleted
  int compareTo(Object other) {
    eventType <=> other.eventType ?: eventDate <=> other.eventDate ?: comments <=> other.comments
  }
}
```

Here's how I reference reminders in the form:

```
<div class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: personInstance, field: 'reminders', 'error')} required">
  <label for="reminders">
    <g:message code="person.reminders.label" default="Reminders" />
    <span class="required-indicator">*</span>
  </label>
  <div id="childList">
    <g:Each var="reminder" in="${personInstance.reminders}" status="i">
    <div id="reminder${i}"> 
      <g:select name="remindersList[${i}].eventType" from="${reminder?.constraints?.eventType?.inList}" required="" value="${reminder?.eventType}" />
      <g:datePicker name="remindersList[${i}].eventDate" precision="day"  value="${reminder?.eventDate}"  />
      <g:textField name="remindersList[${i}].comments" required="" value="${reminder?.comments}"/>
      <input type="hidden" name='remindersList[${i}]._deleted' id='remindersList[${i}]._deleted' value='false'/>
    </div>
    </g:each>
  </div>
</div>
```

And part of the trace showing what's being persisted. At the beggining I'm logging what's being captured from the form, everything ok so far, but then when Person gets saved the remindes collection seems to be empty.

```
2015-07-13 12:22:13,469 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG rescate.personService  - par: remindersList[0].comments=jon5com
2015-07-13 12:22:13,470 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG rescate.PersonService  - par: remindersList[0]=[eventType:nacimiento, eventDate:date.struct, eventDate_day:13, eventDate_month:7, eventDate_year:2015, comments:jon5com, _deleted:false]
2015-07-13 12:22:13,470 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG rescate.PersonService  - par: daten_month=7
2015-07-13 12:22:13,470 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG rescate.PersonService  - par: datein_year=2015
2015-07-13 12:22:13,470 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG rescate.PersonService  - par: remindersList[0].eventType=nacimiento
2015-07-13 12:22:13,470 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG rescate.PersonService  - par: remindersList[0]._deleted=false
2015-07-13 12:22:13,470 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG rescate.PersonService  - par: daten_year=2015
2015-07-13 12:22:13,470 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG rescate.PersonService  - par: dist=crt
2015-07-13 12:22:13,470 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG rescate.PersonService  - par: remindersList[0].eventDate_day=13
2015-07-13 12:22:13,472 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG rescate.PersonService  - par: create=Create
2015-07-13 12:22:13,472 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG rescate.PersonService  - par: remindersList[0].eventDate_year=2015
2015-07-13 12:22:13,472 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG rescate.PersonService  - par: datein_day=13
2015-07-13 12:22:13,472 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG rescate.PersonService  - par: name=jon5
2015-07-13 12:22:13,472 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG rescate.PersonService  - par: loop=cm
2015-07-13 12:22:13,472 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG rescate.PersonService  - par: datein=date.struct
2015-07-13 12:22:13,473 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG rescate.PersonService  - par: gnd=m
2015-07-13 12:22:13,473 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG rescate.PersonService  - par: tim=1m
2015-07-13 12:22:13,473 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG rescate.PersonService  - par: dateOfIntake_month=7
2015-07-13 12:22:13,473 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG rescate.PersonService  - par: remindersList[0].eventDate_month=7
2015-07-13 12:22:13,474 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG rescate.PersonService  - par: dateNeutered_day=13
2015-07-13 12:22:13,475 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG rescate.PersonService  - par: remindersList[0].eventDate=date.struct
2015-07-13 12:22:13,475 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG rescate.PersonService  - par: dateNeutered=date.struct
2015-07-13 12:22:13,475 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG rescate.PersonService  - par: spc=notes2
2015-07-13 12:22:13,475 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG rescate.PersonService  - par: action=save
2015-07-13 12:22:13,475 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG rescate.PersonService  - par: format=null
2015-07-13 12:22:13,475 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG rescate.PersonService  - par: controller=person
2015-07-13 12:22:13,615 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] TRACE internal.SessionImpl  - Setting flush mode to: MANUAL
2015-07-13 12:22:13,616 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] TRACE internal.SessionImpl  - Setting flush mode to: AUTO
2015-07-13 12:22:13,616 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate  - Found thread-bound Session for HibernateTemplate
2015-07-13 12:22:13,617 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] TRACE internal.SessionImpl  - Setting flush mode to: MANUAL
2015-07-13 12:22:13,617 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] TRACE internal.AbstractSaveEventListener  - Transient instance of: org.ppl.Person
2015-07-13 12:22:13,617 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] TRACE internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener  - Saving transient instance
2015-07-13 12:22:13,618 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] TRACE internal.AbstractSaveEventListener  - Saving [org.ppl.Person#<null>]
2015-07-13 12:22:13,618 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] TRACE internal.Cascade  - Processing cascade ACTION_SAVE_UPDATE for: org.ppl.Person
2015-07-13 12:22:13,618 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] TRACE internal.Cascade  - Done processing cascade ACTION_SAVE_UPDATE for: org.ppl.Person
2015-07-13 12:22:13,618 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] TRACE internal.Versioning  - Seeding: 0
2015-07-13 12:22:13,618 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] TRACE spi.ActionQueue  - Adding an EntityIdentityInsertAction for [org.ppl.Person] object
2015-07-13 12:22:13,618 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] TRACE spi.ActionQueue  - Executing inserts before finding non-nullable transient entities for early insert: [EntityIdentityInsertAction[org.ppl.Person#<null>]]
2015-07-13 12:22:13,619 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] TRACE spi.ActionQueue  - Adding insert with no non-nullable, transient entities: [EntityIdentityInsertAction[org.ppl.Person#<null>]]
2015-07-13 12:22:13,619 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] TRACE spi.ActionQueue  - Executing insertions before resolved early-insert
2015-07-13 12:22:13,619 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG spi.ActionQueue  - Executing identity-insert immediately
2015-07-13 12:22:13,619 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] TRACE internal.SessionImpl  - Setting flush mode to: MANUAL
2015-07-13 12:22:13,621 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] TRACE entity.AbstractEntityPersister  - Inserting entity: org.ppl.Person (native id)
2015-07-13 12:22:13,621 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] TRACE entity.AbstractEntityPersister  - Version: 0
2015-07-13 12:22:13,622 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG hibernate.SQL  - insert into animal (id, version, Gnd, daten, datein, tim, spc, name, dist, loop) values (null, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2015-07-13 12:22:13,623 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] TRACE internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl  - Registering statement [prep38: insert into animal (id, version, Gnd, daten, datein, edad, spc, name, dist, loop) values (null, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]
2015-07-13 12:22:13,623 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] TRACE entity.AbstractEntityPersister  - Dehydrating entity: [org.ppl.Person#<null>]
2015-07-13 12:22:13,624 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] TRACE sql.BasicBinder  - binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [0]
2015-07-13 12:22:13,624 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] TRACE sql.BasicBinder  - binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - [Male]
2015-07-13 12:22:13,624 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] TRACE sql.BasicBinder  - binding parameter [3] as [TIMESTAMP] - [Mon Jul 13 00:00:00 ART 2015]
2015-07-13 12:22:13,624 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] TRACE sql.BasicBinder  - binding parameter [4] as [TIMESTAMP] - [Mon Jul 13 00:00:00 ART 2015]
2015-07-13 12:22:13,626 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] TRACE sql.BasicBinder  - binding parameter [5] as [VARCHAR] - [1m]
2015-07-13 12:22:13,626 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] TRACE sql.BasicBinder  - binding parameter [6] as [VARCHAR] - [notes2]
2015-07-13 12:22:13,626 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] TRACE sql.BasicBinder  - binding parameter [7] as [VARCHAR] - [jon5]
2015-07-13 12:22:13,627 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] TRACE sql.BasicBinder  - binding parameter [8] as [VARCHAR] - [crt]
2015-07-13 12:22:13,627 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] TRACE sql.BasicBinder  - binding parameter [9] as [VARCHAR] - [cm]
2015-07-13 12:22:13,628 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG id.IdentifierGeneratorHelper  - Natively generated identity: 2
2015-07-13 12:22:13,628 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] TRACE internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl  - Releasing result set [rs42: org.h2.result.LocalResult@2a3ba9ee columns: 1 rows: 1 pos: 0]
2015-07-13 12:22:13,628 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] TRACE internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl  - Closing result set [rs42: org.h2.result.LocalResult@2a3ba9ee columns: 1 rows: 1 pos: 0]
2015-07-13 12:22:13,631 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] TRACE internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl  - Releasing statement [prep38: insert into animal (id, version, Gnd, daten, datein, tim, spc, name, dist, loop) values (null, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) {1: 0, 2: 'Male', 3: TIMESTAMP '2015-07-13 00:00:00.0', 4: TIMESTAMP '2015-07-13 00:00:00.0', 5: '1m', 6: 'notes2', 7: 'jon5', 8: 'crt', 9: 'cm'}]
2015-07-13 12:22:13,631 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] TRACE internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl  - Closing prepared statement [prep38: insert into animal (id, version, Gnd, daten, datein, tim, spc, name, dist, loop) values (null, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) {1: 0, 2: 'Male', 3: TIMESTAMP '2015-07-13 00:00:00.0', 4: TIMESTAMP '2015-07-13 00:00:00.0', 5: '1m', 6: 'notes2', 7: 'jon5', 8: 'crt', 9: 'cm'}]
2015-07-13 12:22:13,631 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] TRACE internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl  - Starting after statement execution processing [ON_CLOSE]
2015-07-13 12:22:13,632 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] TRACE internal.UnresolvedEntityInsertActions  - No unresolved entity inserts that depended on [[org.ppl.Person#2]]
2015-07-13 12:22:13,633 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] TRACE internal.Cascade  - Processing cascade ACTION_SAVE_UPDATE for: org.ppl.Person
2015-07-13 12:22:13,633 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] TRACE internal.Cascade  - Cascade ACTION_SAVE_UPDATE for collection: org.ppl.Person.reminders
2015-07-13 12:22:13,633 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] TRACE internal.Cascade  - Done cascade ACTION_SAVE_UPDATE for collection: org.ppl.Person.reminders
2015-07-13 12:22:13,633 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] TRACE internal.Cascade  - Done processing cascade ACTION_SAVE_UPDATE for: org.ppl.Person
2015-07-13 12:22:13,633 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] TRACE internal.AbstractSaveEventListener  - Persistent instance of: org.ppl.Person
2015-07-13 12:22:13,633 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] TRACE internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener  - Ignoring persistent instance
2015-07-13 12:22:13,634 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] TRACE internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener  - Object already associated with session: [org.ppl.Person#2]
2015-07-13 12:22:13,634 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] TRACE internal.UnresolvedEntityInsertActions  - No entity insert actions have non-nullable, transient entity dependencies.
2015-07-13 12:22:13,635 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] TRACE internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener  - Flushing session
2015-07-13 12:22:13,635 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener  - Processing flush-time cascades
2015-07-13 12:22:13,635 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] TRACE internal.Cascade  - Processing cascade ACTION_SAVE_UPDATE for: org.ppl.Person
2015-07-13 12:22:13,635 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] TRACE internal.Cascade  - Cascade ACTION_SAVE_UPDATE for collection: org.ppl.Person.reminders
2015-07-13 12:22:13,635 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] TRACE internal.Cascade  - Done cascade ACTION_SAVE_UPDATE for collection: org.ppl.Person.reminders
2015-07-13 12:22:13,635 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] TRACE internal.Cascade  - Done processing cascade ACTION_SAVE_UPDATE for: org.ppl.Person
2015-07-13 12:22:13,635 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener  - Dirty checking collections
2015-07-13 12:22:13,635 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] TRACE internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener  - Flushing entities and processing referenced collections
2015-07-13 12:22:13,636 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] TRACE internal.WrapVisitor  - Wrapped collection in role: org.ppl.Person.reminders
2015-07-13 12:22:13,636 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG internal.Collections  - Collection found: [org.ppl.Person.reminders#2], was: [<unreferenced>] (initialized)
2015-07-13 12:22:13,636 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] TRACE internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener  - Processing unreferenced collections
2015-07-13 12:22:13,636 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] TRACE internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener  - Scheduling collection removes/(re)creates/updates
2015-07-13 12:22:13,637 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener  - Flushed: 0 insertions, 0 updates, 0 deletions to 1 objects
2015-07-13 12:22:13,637 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener  - Flushed: 1 (re)creations, 0 updates, 0 removals to 1 collections
2015-07-13 12:22:13,637 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG util.EntityPrinter  - Listing entities:
2015-07-13 12:22:13,637 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG util.EntityPrinter  - org.ppl.Person{loop=cm, name=jon5, id=2, imagenes=null, datein=Mon Jul 13 00:00:00 ART 2015, Gnd=Male, tim=1m, dist=crt, reminders=[], daten=Mon Jul 13 00:00:00 ART 2015, spc=notes2, version=0}
2015-07-13 12:22:13,638 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] TRACE internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener  - Executing flush
2015-07-13 12:22:13,638 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG collection.AbstractCollectionPersister  - Inserting collection: [org.ppl.Person.reminders#2]
2015-07-13 12:22:13,639 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG collection.AbstractCollectionPersister  - Collection was empty
```

Any clues will be welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. I was following an example (http://www.2paths.com/2009/10/01/one-to-many-relationships-in-grails-forms/) where the LazyList is accessed through a getter, and the form fields would reference this 'expandable' list.. Well, that was the issue, the form fields obviously need to have the name of the domain's collection list so grails can perform the data-binding. My approach: in order to add new fields to the form I use ajax to call an action in the controller, get a new child and render a template with it, then in the form I append the template to the list of childs.
As for the creation, I just rely on grails data-binding.
I'm still not sure WHY or HOW in the example from 2paths above this is done through the expandable list.

```
class Author {
  static constraints = {    }
  String name
  List books = new ArrayList()
  static hasMany = [ books:Book ]
  static mapping = {
      books cascade:"all-delete-orphan"
  }
  def getExpandableBookList() {
      return lazyList.decorate(books,FactoryUtils.instantiateFactory(Book.class))
  }
}
```